# How to downcast shared_ptr without std::static_pointer_cast in C++?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, downcast

we use EASTL and I can't use std::static_pointer_cast.
I receive a pointer to base class in my function and don't know, how to correctly cast it:

```
    switch (command.code)
    {
..
    case CommandCode::firstCase:
        firstCaseFunction(std::shared_ptr<firstCaseType>(static_cast<firstCaseType*>(command.context.get())));
        break;
    case CommandCode::secondCase:
        secondCaseFunction(std::shared_ptr<secondCaseType>(static_cast<secondCaseType*>(command.context.get())));
        break;
..
    default:
        break;
    }
```

The code above compiles, but throws some exception in the end of `firstCaseFunction`/`secondCaseFunction` (I don't see the exception, probably because we don't even support exceptions in our code).

The code doesn't look correct, but I can't find correct solution for this problem and I tried many versions, but none of them worked.
I think there is a problem with lifetime of the casted smart pointer objects.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<firstCaseType>(static_cast<firstCaseType*>(command.context.get()))
```

This extracts a non-owning raw pointer from `context`'s ownership network, and passes it to a new `std::shared_ptr` as if it were owning. The solution is to use `std::shared_ptr`'s aliasing constructor ([overload #8 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)):

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<firstCaseType>(command.context, static_cast<firstCaseType*>(command.context.get()))
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yes, something like that! I couldn't find it and didn't know, how it's called.

Comment: And wrap this in a function, `totally_not_std::static_pointer_cast`

Answer (score 1):

The code is most certainly wrong. You end up having two shared pointers managing the same underlying raw pointer. What you need here is an **aliasing** version of shared ptr (see full example below):

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo { };

struct Boo : Foo { };

void g(std::shared_ptr<Foo> f)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Boo> p(f, static_cast<Boo*>(f.get()));
}
```